# Getting current time in UTC and converting String to long

Tags: java

I have to do the following operation:

```
public long getDifference(String time) {
    long diff = <CURRENT TIME IN UTC> - <PARAMETER TIME>;

    return diff;
}
```

So 2 questions:

1. How can I get the current time in UTC?
2. How can I convert the String time parameter (format `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss`) to a long?

Comment: `return System.currentTimeMillis() - new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(time).getTime();`

Answer (score 0):

1. Using `System.currentTimeMillis()`  you can get local time
2. If u want to get UTC time I think you should do:
   `current time - zone offset - daylight saving time`
3. Time format: `new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").parse(time).getTime()`